# AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate photoOutput() not called every time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I'm [following this tutorial](https://kavsoft.dev/swiftui_2.0/custom_camera) creating a custom camera for my app. After capturing a picture, the user can continue to another view where the image is displayed. Unfortunately, sometimes the image is not displayed on the next page at all, and other times it works perfectly fine. It appears that my delegate function is not being called all the time:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {...}
```

**My Camera Model**

```
class CameraModel: NSObject,ObservableObject,AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
    
    @Published var isTaken = false
    
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    
    @Published var alert = false
    
    // since were going to read pic data....
    @Published var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    // preview....
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    @Published var image = UIImage()
    
    func Check(){
        
        // first checking camerahas got permission...
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
            setUp()
            return
            // Setting Up Session
        case .notDetermined:
            // retusting for permission....
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                
                if status{
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
            
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    func setUp(){
        
        // setting up camera...
        
        do{
            
            // setting configs...
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            
            // change for your own...
            
            let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            
            // checking and adding to session...
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(input){
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
            
            // same for output....
            
            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
                self.session.addOutput(self.output)
            }
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    // take and retake functions...
    
    func takePic(){
        
        self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            
            self.session.stopRunning()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
            }
        }
    }
    
    func reTake(){
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            
            self.session.startRunning()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
            }
        }
    }
    
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        print("reached")
        
        if error != nil{
            return
        }
        
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else{return}
        
        guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else {return}
        
        self.image = uiImage
        
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, "reached" is only sometimes printed, hence the reason why my next view only sometimes contains the UIImage. I'm not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: I had the same problem, I found a solution here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080121/swiftui-server-not-receiving-base64-string/69125035#69125035)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the session is getting ended before the photo is finished processing. It happens only some of the time, because we don't know exactly when the session will end since it is happening asynchronously. I added debug statements to the other delegate functions:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willBeginCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
    print("will begin")
}
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didCapturePhotoFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
    print("did capture")
}
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, error: Error?) {
    print("did finish capture")
}
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    print("did finish processing photo") }
```

In my case, I often saw the "did capture" output only. Now, you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080121/swiftui-server-not-receiving-base64-string/69125035#69125035) solution to fix this, but it is not the best solution. It works because the `session.stopRunning()` call is delayed long enough to let the photo finish processing, but this solution is not guaranteed to work always and may even cause a longer delay than needed. A better solution would be to just move the `session.stopRunning()` logic into the delegate function, so that you know it will wait until the photo is processed, and stop the session immediately after. Now, your methods look like this:

```
func takePic() {
    self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil{
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.session.stopRunning()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
        }
    }
    
    guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else{return}
    guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else {return}
    self.image = uiImage
}
```