# SwiftUI- server not receiving base64 string

Tags: json, swift, post, base64

What I'm trying to do is take a picture, encode it to base64 and then send it in a dictionary to my server. When I send the dictionary over, sometimes it sends with the base64 and sometimes it sends without it even if I don't make any changes.
Here's the code for the camera view

```
struct CameraView: View {

@StateObject var camera = CameraModel()

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        CameraPreview(camera: camera)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
        
        VStack{
            if camera.isTaken{
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: camera.retake, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.camera")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    })
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                }
            }
    
            Spacer()
            
            HStack{
                if camera.isTaken{
                    Button(action: camera.sendPicData , label: {
                        Text("Save")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .padding(.vertical, 10)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                    })
                    .padding(.leading)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                else{
                    Button(action: camera.takePic, label: {
                        ZStack{
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                            
                            Circle()
                                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 75)
        }
    }
    .onAppear(perform: {
        camera.Check()
    })
}
}

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable{

@ObservedObject var camera: CameraModel

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    
    camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
    camera.preview.frame = view.frame
    
    camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
    
    camera.session.startRunning()
    
    return view
    
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    
}
}
```

and the code for taking the picture and sending it to server

```
class CameraModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
@Published var isTaken = false
@Published var alert = false
@Published var sendPic = false
@Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
@Published var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
@Published var preview: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
@Published var picData = Data(count: 0)

func Check(){
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
    case .authorized:
        setUp()
        return
    case .notDetermined:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
            if status{
                self.setUp()
            }
        }
    case .denied:
        self.alert.toggle()
        return
    default:
        return
    }
}

func setUp(){
    do{
        self.session.beginConfiguration()
        
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
        
        if self.session.canAddInput(input){
            self.session.addInput(input)
        }
        
        if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
            self.session.addOutput(self.output)
        }
        self.session.commitConfiguration()
    }
    catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func takePic(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
        self.session.stopRunning()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
        }
        print("pic taken...")
    }
}

func retake(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.session.startRunning()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
        }
    }
}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil{
        return
    }
    
    guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else{return}
    self.picData = imageData
}

func sendPicData(){
    let image = UIImage(data: self.picData)
    let imageData: Data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) ?? Data()
    let imageString: String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
            
    let dictionary:[String:String] = ["Dot":imageString]
    if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [.prettyPrinted]) {

        guard let sendURL = URL(string:"http://toServer") else {
            print("invalid URL")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: sendURL)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = theJSONData

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                print ("PUT Failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error")")
                return
            }
        }.resume()

        print(dictionary)
    }
}
}
```

I don't know why it's so inconsistent. It doesn't make any sense to me, if it works once why wouldn't it work every time? Help Please

Comment: Why would you convert the json data to string and back to data? Just use the `theJSONData`

Comment: The only place where it could fail is that `UIImage(data: self.picData)` is nil... But since we don't know what's `picData`...

Comment: @LeoDabus because when I don't have it going back to data it gives me an error saying "value of type [String:String] has no member data". Where do you recommend putting theJSONData because I commented out theJSONText and changed let POST = theJSONData! but it gives me the error "value of type Data has no member data"

Comment: @Larme picData is                                                                                                  
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, 
        didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
            if error != nil{
                return
            }
        
            guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else{return}
             self.picData = imageData
        }

Comment: `request.httpBody = theJSONData` should be enough. No need for `theJSONText` or `POST`. You can keep `theJSONText` for debug purposes though...

Comment: `jpegData(compressionQuality:)` can be nil, see the discussion of the documentation. To check if that's the case then...

Comment: @Larme I made the changes you suggested and it's still inconsistent, I put a pagebreak and it says image = (UIImage?)nil, so i guess you were right but I don't know what to do because this is where I combined 2 separate youtube videos

Comment: `self.picData` can't be nil since `UIImage(data:)` expect a non-nil value. So did you declare `var picData = Data()`? If that's the case, could it be that `picData` isEmpty? Could you check if that's the case? What calls `sendPicData`?

Comment: @Larme this is the code for picData, in the youtube vid the guy uses this to save the photo to his camera roll but I used it for what I was trying to do.`func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil{
            return
        }
        
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else{return}
        self.picData = imageData
    }` I just have a button that calls on sendPicData which works every time but the server doesn't receive the base64 every time, it'll just show up empty

Comment: I saw that code, please add it in your question instead. Also, could you say where is defined `picData` and how? And where is called `sendPicData()`?

Comment: @Larme i defined picData in `func photoOutput`. I added the missing things to the question

Comment: No, you set picData in `photoOutput`, it's not where you defined it... Where did you write `var picData`? Also, where is set `isTaken`? If you reproduce the bug, can you ensure by adding a log before `self.picData = imageData`, that this line is really called when having an issue?

Comment: @Larme lol sorry I'm dumb, I was trying to avoid putting my whole script on here but idc anymore so now you should be able to see everything I've done... and also I appreciate all the help so far

Comment: `isTaken.toggle()`, but if you call retake, isToken is false, no? That's strange... You should set it to `true` when you take or retake, no? But your issue is that you read `isTaken` while in fact, you should be able to `sendPicData` ONLY when `self.picData = imageData` has been set. For instance, the delegate method `didFinishProcessingPhoto` will be called AFTER, so you still might have `picData` with value `Data(count: 0)` when trying to send the data... See? There is a "synchronization" issue...

Comment: @Larme I see what you mean now but I still don't know what to do. I tried replacing `isTaken.toggle()` with `isTaken = true` for take and retake but it was still inconsistent.

Comment: I also made a var `didFinishProcessing = false` and made it `= true` in my delegate function `photoOutput`. I made it so when `sendPicData` is called it won't send unless `if didFinishProcessing == true` so that the delegate function will be called BEFORE `sendPicData` is called. I think that should've solved the synchronization problem but it still was inconsistent. I saw that other people were having the same problem that the delegate function wasn't being called all the time

Comment: And you set `didFinishProcessing` on `false` before calling `capturePhoto(with:)`, right? I didn't see the issue about the delegate method not being called, but for instance, you check on `error` existence in it. Check if you set all variables correctly? Also, on `retake`, do you "clear/reset" `picData`?

Comment: @Larme yes it's false before I call on `caputurePhoto(with:)`. I put a print statement in the delegate function and I can see that the code works when the delegate function is called before `func takePic`. But they are called at the same time when I press the button for `camera.takePic` so I guess it's still a synchronization problem like you said. I think my variables are all correct and reseting `picData` back to `Data(count: 0)` in `retake` didn't do anything.

Comment: @Larme Okay I've been messing around in my `func takePic` and I've found that if I do `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { (timer) in                 self.session.stopRunning()             }` which I believe gave the delegate function a little bit more time to be called on. Well it works every time as far as I can tell, but when I take the picture the picture doesn't stay on the screen anymore which is weird. So I have it working now I just have a UI problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the delegate function `func photoOutput()` wasn't being called every time the picture was taken. I found that in `func takePic()`, if I put a `Timer` on `self.session.stopRunning()` it would fix the problem and call the delegate function every time but it would also cause another problem that would stop calling on `self.isTaken.toggle()`. To fix that I put the `Timer` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` like so

```
func takePic(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { (timer) in
                self.session.stopRunning()
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}
        }
        print("pic taken...")
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this but I've seen a lot of other people with the same similar problem and with this solution it will call the delegate function every time.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you toggling the isTaken before (it is).

I think the issue here is that you are allowing the photo to be saved (showing the button) before the take photo thread has completed.

```
func takePic(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
        self.session.stopRunning()
        
        //DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //    withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()}  // << IT ISNT TAKEN YET
        //}
        //print("pic taken...")  // << AGAIN IT ISNT TAKEN YET
    }
}
```

When the takePic thread has finished it calls the delegate (callback):

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

    // NOW ITS TAKEN BUT MAY HAVE ERRORS

    if error != nil{
        return  // MAYBE THIS NEED SOME BETTER FEEDBACK FOR THE USER
    }
    
    guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else{return}  // USER FEEDBACK??

    self.picData = imageData

    // NOW ITS TAKEN


    // I'm assuming this is running on the main thread.
    withAnimation{self.isTaken.toggle()} // SO TOGGLE isTaken
}
```

I'm writing this without testing but I think you are confusing how callbacks work.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29

func photoOutput here is the callback (unless I'm missing something here as I'm quite new to SwiftUI myself).